# ldap_search ignoring the case letter

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

hello my friends i'm trying to get some data from the active directory but i have a problem when the stored eamil in capital letters or mixed letters , i want the ldap_search() to search the AD ignoring the case of the letters 
here's my function and thank you in advance

```
    function LDAPget($email)
    {
        $ldap['server'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
        $ldap['user'] = 'x';
        $ldap['pass'] = 'any';
        $ds = ldap_connect($ldap['server']); 
        $bind = ldap_bind($ds, $ldap['user'], $ldap['pass']);
        $filter = "(mail=$email)";
        $sr = ldap_search($ds, $ldap['base_dn'], $filter, array('*'));
        $rows = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the strcasecmp function did the trick

```
    if (strcasecmp($rows[0][$filtername][0], $usereinfo) == 0 ) {

//problem solved 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP client must use the `exactMatch` matching rule in the filter. Which `caseExact` matching rule is used depends on the attribute definition, which is stored in the schema. Each attribute has its own attribute type, syntax, matching rules, and other information. If the LDAP Directory Server is not LDAP compliant, extensible match filters might not be supported, in which case, the application must process the data retrieved from the LDAP directory server.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: the application must process the data retrieved from the LDAP directory server.
 see the problem is : when i enter for example email different from the email stored in the AD e.g: ro@test.com and the stored email is Ro@test.com the server will not give me any result how can I solve this problem

Comment: typically, but not always, the components of an email address is stored in an attribute which has the `caseIgnoreMatch` matching rule (who knows what AD does). `ro@test.com` and `RO@test.com` are equivalent and the server should return either if the filter used by the client calls for the default matching rule for that attribute. I see that the filter in use does not specify a matching rule, so the default matching rule should be used and any case of `ro@test.com` should be returned to the client. Assuming the LDAP server is not broken, something else is prevent the data from being returned.

Comment: I see ...so can i change the matching rule with my application??? or should i call the administrator server to see the problem from their AD attribute

Comment: The LDAP client cannot change the matching rule unless it has access to the schema, and even so, it's probably not necessary. I would suggest using a known good tool like `ldapsearch` to retrieve data from the LDAP server to ensure that the data is there and looks as expected.

Comment: it didn't work yet my friend i have some change in the question